# Automapper missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping error

Tags: asp.net

I am using Auto mapper and I am getting this error, I am getting this error within AddAsync() method. Please help me out to solve this issue.

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nDepartmentsViewModel -> Departments\r\nEmployeeAttendanceApp.ViewModels.DepartmentsViewModel -> EmployeeAttendanceApp.Models.StaffManagement.Departments
```

My class

```
public interface IMapperConfig
{
    IMapper CreateMapper();
}

public class MapperConfig : IMapperConfig
{
    public IMapper CreateMapper()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
       {
           cfg.CreateMap<RegisterStaffs, RegisterStaffViewModel>();
           cfg.CreateMap<AttendanceRecorder, AttendanceRecorderViewModel>();
           cfg.CreateMap<ManageLeaves, ManageLeavesViewModel>();
           cfg.CreateMap<RegisterDevices, RegisterDevicesViewModel>();
           cfg.CreateMap<Departments, DepartmentsViewModel>();

       });

        return config.CreateMapper();
    }
}
```

---

```
      public class DepartmentsViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("اسم القسم/ الادارة")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "الرجاء ادخال اسم القسم")]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("اضافة ملاحظات القسم")]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public bool? IsUpdated { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string DeletedBy { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("عدد الموظفيين")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage =  " الرحاء إدخال عدد موظفيين القسم")]
    public long? StaffNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RegisterDevicesViewModel> RegisterDevices { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RegisterStaffViewModel> RegisterStaffs { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
     public partial class Departments
{
    
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public bool? IsUpdated { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string DeletedBy { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public long? StaffNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RegisterDevices> RegisterDevices { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RegisterStaffs> RegisterStaffs { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
       **I am getting the error in this method** 

      public async Task<bool> AddAsync(DepartmentsViewModel departmentsView)
    {
        try
        {
            var department = mapper.Map<DepartmentsViewModel, Departments>(departmentsView);
            await context.Departments.AddAsync(department);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

---

```
       //here is startup file where I have registered the services  
        services.AddSingleton<IMapperConfig, MapperConfig>();

        services.AddTransient<IDepartmentManager, DepartmentManager>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by adding .ReverseMap() inside MapperConfig class

cfg.CreateMap<Departments, DepartmentsViewModel>().ReverseMap();

but still I can't understand why it didn't work previously with out it because I have seen various examples never using ReverseMap()